# Put a List from a Json to a Dropdown button

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to put a list (that comes from a json) into a dropdown but i dont know how to do it, have tried some things but couldnt make it work.

I have this list and this function to retrieve the data from the api:

(the loadFuncionarios i run on the initstate, so when i load the screen i already have the data disponible to put on the dropdown)

```
  List funcionariosList = <Funcionarios>[];

  Future loadFuncionarios() async {
    Response response;
    Dio dio = new Dio();
    String url = 'http://192.168.15.4:8090/api/funcionarios';
    response = await dio.post(url);

    FuncionariosList funcionariosList =
        FuncionariosList.fromJson(response.data);
    print(funcionariosList.funcionarios[0].nome);//Just a test
    print(funcionariosList.funcionarios.length);
  }
```

And i have this dropdown:

```
DropdownButton(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    iconEnabledColor: Colors.blue[900],
                    value: _value,
                    items: [
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: Text("Test"),
                        value: 1,
                      ),
           
                    ],
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _value = value;
                      });
                    }),
```

My list os Funcionarios haves a string Nome, which i would like to be the itens for the dropdown list, how can i do it?

Comment: Pay attention, you are shadowing (redefining) `functionariosList` inside `loadFuncionarios()`

Answer (score 1):

To get access to the data, you'll have to map the list out in items:

```
items: funcionariosList.map((funcionario) => DropdownMenuItem()).toList();
```

You can change the 'funcionario' to whatever you would like to call it.  Now, you can access the data of each item using dot notation (funcionario.name for example);

```
FutureBuilder<List<Functionario>>(
  future: loadFunctionarios();
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
  functionariosList = snapshot.data == null ? List<Functionario>() : snapshot.data;
    DropdownButton(
                isExpanded: true,
                iconEnabledColor: Colors.blue[900],
                value: _value,
                items: funcionariosList.map((funcionario) => DropdownMenuItem()).toList();
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _value = value;
                  });
                }),
  });
```

Also, change you function to this:

```
  Future<List<Functionario>> loadFuncionarios() async {
Response response;
Dio dio = new Dio();
String url = 'http://192.168.15.4:8090/api/funcionarios';
response = await dio.post(url);

print(funcionariosList.funcionarios[0].nome);//Just a test
print(funcionariosList.funcionarios.length);

return FuncionariosList.fromJson(response.data);
}
```

I'm assuming the model is called Functionario.

Comment: I should put this in "items" (inside the dropdownbutton)? When i try i get the error "The method 'DropDownMenuItem' isn't defined for the type '_OSState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'DropDownMenuItem'.dart(undefined_method)"

Comment: It was misspelled.  It's supposed to be DropdownMenuItem, not DropDownMenuItem.  I fixed my answer.

Comment: I have tried but stil not working, the dropdown its empty (but there are no errors shown).

Comment: That means, your loadFunctionarios function isn't loading anything before the dropdown builds.  You will have to wrap your Dopdown in a FutureBuilder, so it rebuilds when it has the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use `FutureBuilder`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends HookWidget {
  Future<List<String>> _loadFunctionarios = Future<List<String>>.delayed(
    Duration(seconds: 2),
    () => ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _choice = useState('C');
    return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
      future: _loadFunctionarios,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? DropdownButton(
                isExpanded: true,
                iconEnabledColor: Colors.blue[900],
                value: _choice.value,
                items: snapshot.data
                    .map(
                      (functionario) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: functionario,
                        child: Text(functionario),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
                onChanged: (value) => _choice.value = value,
              )
            : Text('Loading...');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what should i put on "A B C"  part?

Comment: This is just a dummy method returning a `Future`. [1] Replace this dummy `_loadFunctionarios` by your own. [2] Replace `Text(functionario)` by, probably (depends on your `Functionario` class) `Text(functionario.name)`.